# c++ - wrong destructor gets called

Tags: c++, destructor

I have an understanding problem with destructors.

In the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X{
public:
    int id;
    X(int id){
        this->id = id;
    }
    ~X(){
        cout << "destroying " << id;
    }

};



int main(){


    X a(1);
    a = X(2);


    while(true);
    return 0;

}
```

I get the following output: *destroying 2*

This is totally unexpected to me, because I thought that the destructor gets always called, when an object stops to exist.

But in this example, it's object 1 that stops to exist and gets replaced by object 2. But instead of calling the destructor of object 1, the destructor of object 2 gets called.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: a only stops to exist after main returns, during that it never stops to exist, you only ever assign to it using op=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a = X(2); => expression call assignment operator and a.id data member is initialized by temporaryobject.id i.e 2.

a = X(2); => expression calls the default assignment operator that is provided by compiler and do the sallow copy.

X(2) expression create the temporary object and temporaryobject.id is initialized with 2.

First time deconstruct get call when temporary object get called another for a object.

Answer (score 5):

In your case, only one object gets destroyed - namely, the temporary `X(2)` on the right-hand side of your assignment. The original `X(1)` does not get destroyed, because it gets overwritten by the assignment. When the time comes for it to get destroyed, it will print `destroying 2` as well.

However, the modified `X(2)` (that started off as `X(1)`) is kept alive by the infinite loop, so it does not get destroyed either. Removing the infinite loop fixes this ([demo](http://ideone.com/xdJo6v)).

Comment: This is a very good answer, but I was only aple to understand it after reading @PlasmaHH's comment mentioning the assignment operator. I think you should mention this in your answer, too ;) Because it first, I thought (1) should get destroyed and then its space in memory should get filled with a new copy of (2). But what instead happens is, that (1) just gets modified to match (2)

Comment: @VanCoding I say "assignment" twice, assuming that you know that it's an operator :)

Comment: I know, but an assignment can get interpreted differently, as you can see :D I thought the memory gets assigned, and not a function gets called that converts (1) to (2)